# Subtracting Item from Array in BigQuery

Tags: sql, google-analytics, google-bigquery

I've got a query that keeps track of items in a shopping cart as a user adds items to it. I've got the adding items part down, but I'm having trouble removing a single item based on a given action. Here's an example:

```
SELECT
  *,
  -- Remove item from cart where item in cart
  CASE WHEN cart_action = 'remove from cart' THEN (SELECT SPLIT(cart, ',') - SPLIT(cart, ',') WHERE SPLIT(cart, ',') = item)
FROM
(
SELECT 
  'remove from cart' AS cart_action,
  'apple' AS item,
  'apple, orange, banana, apple' AS cart
  );
```

If my cart starts out as `'apple, orange, banana, apple'`, then I'd like the output to be `'orange, banana, apple'`. It doesn't matter what order the items are in.

I'd like to just be able to break the cart string into an array, find one matching item in the array, drop that item, and then return the updated cart.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Below example is for BigQuery Standard SQL

```sql
#standardSQL
WITH `action` AS (
  SELECT 
    'remove from cart' AS cart_action,
    'apple' AS item,
    'apple, orange, banana, apple' AS cart
)
SELECT 
  *,
  (SELECT STRING_AGG(cart_item) 
    FROM UNNEST(SPLIT(cart)) cart_item 
    WHERE TRIM(cart_item) != item
  ) new_cart
FROM `action`
```

with result as

```sql
Row cart_action         item    cart                            new_cart     
1   remove from cart    apple   apple, orange, banana, apple    orange, banana, apple
```

Comment: The above answer only works if the value you are trying to match is the first item in the string. If your 'cart' is 'kiwi, apple, orange, banana, apple' then the function removes nothing.

Comment: @JamesMason - `TRIM` in `TRIM(cart_item)`  was missing :o)